# Ajax function not working in Ember.js

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, ember.js

I'm trying to study Ember.js myself and I'm stuck with a problem I want to invoke my server side method using an ajax function but its not working as planned I can call the function and alert the inputs but cant pass the values to server side my current code is given below

```
//Application
App = Em.Application.create();

//Model

App.Users = Em.Object.extend({
    EmailID: null,
    Password: null
});

//View
App.UserTextField = Em.TextField.extend({

});

App.PassTextField = Em.TextField.extend({

});

//controller

App.AlertController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    content: [],
    username: '',
    password: '',
    alertDetails: function () {
        var me = this;
        var username = me.get("username");
        var pass = me.get("password");
        alert(username + ' ' + pass);
        var data = App.Users.create({
            EmailID: username,
            Password: pass,
            passData: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/EmberNewFinal/Home/Create',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("hi");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
});
App.alertController = App.AlertController.create();
```

I cant find the problem with my code please help me to find out

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read [This blog post](http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html) about how to make ember work without ember data. Read it a couple of times until it makes sense.

There are a couple of mistakes in the code. You're making data an object with a passData method. That method is never called, and so the data won't get persisted. Also, you can't reference data within itself and have it work. Better to do something like this.

```
App.AlertController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  content: [],
  username: '',
  password: '',
  alertDetails: function () {
    var data = {'username': this.get("username"),  
                'password': this.get("password")}
    $.ajax({
      url: '/EmberNewFinal/Home/Create',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success: function (response) {
        alert("hi");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Note: this will send the data to your API, but won't store it anywhere in ember. If you want access to that data later, you'll need to store it somwhere. Once again, have a look at [Evil Trout's blog](http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the replay ... and I've one more doubt my current code contains 2 variable to store username and password and I wonder is there any way to store these values into a single object

Comment: You mean the views? Yes, thats not really the right way to do things. Have a look at the video guide on the emberjs site. You simply create your input box in your template and it'll link directly to the fields in the controller.

Comment: @AlenJoy you can always create an `Ember.Object` to encapsulate groups of date. `user: Ember.Object.create({username: null, pass: null})` and then in your template, you can do `{{view Em.TextField valueBinding="user.username"}}` or something like that.